# What is the meaning of the specific digits in eclipse log?

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, plugins

I need  to know what is the meaning of part of the Eclipse log. For example:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.navigator 2 0 2017-03-31 13:07:11.248
!MESSAGE Warning: popupMenuId of ".....
```

After the plugin ID there are 2 and 0, I think the 2 is the severity, which is warning in this case but could  you tell me about the second digit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first number is the severity.

The second number is the 'bundle code' which is an error number from the code generating the error. This is usually from the `IStatus` `getCode` value. For example in:

```
IStatus status = new Status(IStatus.ERROR, "plugin id", 123, "message", exception);

Activator.getLog().log(status);
```

`123` is the error number.

Some plugins such as `org.eclipse.core.resources` use the error number a lot to distinguish different errors (see `IResourceStatus`), other plugins less so.